# JavaScript filter method returning filtered array and empty array

Tags: javascript, filter

I am trying to log the current reading status but instead of getting just the log I am also getting an empty array when calling displayInformation(). How can I get the result I want without an additional empty array? and why is it returning an empty array?

```
function displayInformation() {
  function statusRead(obj){
    if (obj.readingStatus === false) {
      console.log('You still need to read ' + obj.title + ' by ' + obj.author + '.');
    } else {
      console.log('Already read ' + obj.title + ' by' + obj.author + '.');
    }
  }

  var statusFilter = library.filter(statusRead);
  console.log(statusFilter);
}

var library = [ 
    {
        title: 'Bill Gates',
        author: 'The Road Ahead',
        readingStatus: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Steve Jobs',
        author: 'Walter Isaacson',
        readingStatus: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Mockingjay: The Final Book of The Hunger Games',
        author: 'Suzanne Collins',
        readingStatus: false
    }
];

displayInformation();
```

When you invoke displayInformation() this is whats logged to console

```
"Already read Bill Gates byThe Road Ahead."
"Already read Steve Jobs byWalter Isaacson."
"You still need to read Mockingjay: The Final Book of The Hunger Games by Suzanne Collins."
[]
```

Comment: Your `statusRead()` is returning `undefined`, which is why `Array.filter()` is dropping those elements. Instead you should use `library.forEach(statusRead)`

Comment: Before you use an unfamiliar method, [read it's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Then you will know how it works and whether it is right method to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get the result I want without an additional empty array?

You have to use `.forEach()` or a normal `for loop` to do what you want to do. `.filter()` use case is entirely different from yours.

> why is it returning an empty array?

Since the `.filter()` method will return a filtered array, it is returning an empty array in your case as your `callBack` function is returning `undefined` all the time.

---

Your code should have to be like this,

```
function displayInformation(library) {
 library.forEach(function(obj){
    if (obj.readingStatus === false) {
      console.log('You still need to read ' + obj.title + ' by ' + obj.author + '.'); 
    } else { 
      console.log('Already read ' + obj.title + ' by' + obj.author + '.'); 
    }
 });
}

displayInformation(library);
```

---

The pure for-loop version,

```
function displayInformation(library) {
  var i = 0, len = library.length, obj;
  for (; i < len; i++) {
    obj = library[i];
    if (obj.readingStatus === false) {
      console.log('You still need to read ' + obj.title + ' by ' + obj.author + '.');
    } else {
      console.log('Already read ' + obj.title + ' by' + obj.author + '.');
    }
  }
}

displayInformation(library);
```

Comment: can you also give example of using for loop as well?

Comment: @SOSANA Added a pure for-loop version. So you really don't know how to do it by using a for loop?

Comment: since your answer could be done with both, might as well show both :)

Comment: @SOSANA Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're printing out `statusFilter` which is the result of filtering using `statusRead`. Since `statusRead` never returns `true`, the result will be empty. The way that [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) works is it will create a new array from an old array, where it includes every value that returns truthy. For example, here's how you could get all of the even numbers from a list of numbers.

```
var evens = numbers.filter(function(x) {
  return x % 2 === 0;
});
```

So, again, since you are never returning `true` from your `filter` predicate, you're getting an empty list which you proceed to `console.log` out.

To just iterate through a list, you should either use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```
for (var i = 0; i < library.length; i++) {
  var obj = library[i];
  ...
}
```

Or the [`forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
library.forEach(function(obj) {
  ...
});
```